# Inventario de red (Script Visual Basic)

Tags: vbscript

Hola tengo el siguiente script para un inventario de red, lo he probado pero al final del procedimiento me coloca el nombre del pc en las 3 columnas, no me arroja ni la ip de los equipos ni MacAdress me podrían ayudar a encontrar la solución.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Row, XL, WshShell, FileSystem, RegularExpression, Dummy, TheNVFile, 
TheLine
Dim Whacks, WhacksFound, WhacksPattern,  Flag, HostName, NBTable, 
PingReport, PingPattern
Dim IPAddress, MACPattern, MACAddress, Matches, TheMatch, Match, NBCommand, 
TheNBTFile
Dim IPCommand, TheIPFile, FileName, TheDate, Suggestion, Book

Const ForReading = 1
Row = 2

Set XL = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set RegularExpression = New RegExp

Dummy = WshShell.Popup ("Compilando inventario de red.  Por favor                 
espere...",1,"Utilidad para inventario de red",64)

Call BuildSpreadSheet()

WshShell.Run "Cmd.exe /c Net View > C:\Windows\Temp\NetViewList.txt", 2,True
Set TheNVFile = FileSystem.OpenTextFile("C:\Windows\Temp\NetViewList.txt",     ForReading, True)

Do While TheNVFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
TheLine = TheNVFile.ReadLine
Whacks = "\\"
WhacksFound = FindPattern(TheLine, Whacks)
If WhacksFound Then
WhacksPattern = "\\\\\S*"
Flag = "1"
HostName = GetPattern(TheLine, WhacksPattern, Flag )
NBTable = GetNBTable(HostName)
MACPattern = "MAC Address = \S*"
Flag = "2"
MACAddress = GetPattern(NBTable, MACPattern, Flag )
PingReport = GetIPAddress(HostName)
PingPattern = "Reply from \S*"
Flag = "3"
IPAddress = GetPattern(PingReport, PingPattern, Flag )
IPAddress = Replace(IPAddress, ":", "")
Call AddToSpreadSheet(HostName, IPAddress, MACAddress)
End If
Loop

TheNVFile.Close
FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Windows\Temp\NetViewList.txt")
Dummy = WshShell.Popup ("Inventario de red completado",5,"Utilidad para             inventario de red",64 )
Call SaveSpreadSheet()
Wscript.Quit

Sub BuildSpreadSheet()
XL.Visible = True
Set Book = XL.WorkBooks.Add
XL.Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 20
XL.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 20
XL.Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 20
XL.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Nombre Equipo"
XL.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Direccion IP"
XL.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Direccion MAC"
XL.Range("A1:C1").Select
XL.Selection.Font.Bold = True
XL.Selection.Font.Size = 12
End Sub

Sub AddToSpreadSheet(HostName, IPAddress, MACAddress)
XL.Cells(Row, 1).Value = HostName
XL.Cells(Row, 2).Value = IPAddress
XL.Cells(Row, 3).Value = MACAddress
Row = Row + 1
XL.Cells(Row, 1).Select
End Sub
Sub SaveSpreadSheet()
TheDate = Date
TheDate = Replace(TheDate, "/", "-")
Suggestion = "NetAI " & TheDate & ".xls"
FileName = XL.GetSaveAsFilename(Suggestion)
If FileName <> False Then
Book.SaveAs(FileName)
End If
End Sub

Function FindPattern(TheText, ThePattern)
RegularExpression.Pattern = ThePattern
If RegularExpression.Test(TheText) Then
FindPattern = "True"
Else
FindPattern = "False"
End If
End Function

Function GetPattern(TheText, ThePattern, Flag)
RegularExpression.Pattern = ThePattern
Set Matches = RegularExpression.Execute(TheText)
For Each Match in Matches
TheMatch = Match.Value
If Flag = "1" Then TheMatch = Mid(TheMatch, 3)
If Flag = "2" Then TheMatch = Mid(TheMatch, 14)
If Flag = "3" Then TheMatch = Mid(TheMatch, 11)
Next
GetPattern = TheMatch
End Function

Function GetNBTable(HostName)
NBCommand = "nbtstat -a " & HostName
WshShell.Run "Cmd.exe /c " & NBCommand &" > C:\Windows\Temp\NBTList.txt",     2,True
Set TheNBTFile = FileSystem.OpenTextFile("C:\Windows\Temp\NBTList.txt",     ForReading, True)
GetNBTable = TheNBTFile.ReadAll
TheNBTFile.Close
FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Windows\Temp\NBTList.txt")
End Function

Function GetIPAddress(HostName)
IPCommand = "ping -n 1 " & HostName
WshShell.Run "Cmd.exe /c " & IPCommand &" > C:\Windows\Temp\IPList.txt", 2,True
Set TheIPFile = FileSystem.OpenTextFile("C:\Windows\Temp\IPList.txt",     ForReading, True)
GetIPAddress = TheIPFile.ReadAll
TheIPFile.Close
FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Windows\Temp\IPList.txt")
End Function
```

Comment: Tienes un usuario con acceso privilegiado de todas? si es asi, el objeto [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389763(v=vs.85).aspx) junto con las [Classes WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(v=vs.85).aspx) puedes obtener toda clase de informacion respecto a estas. Si estan dentro de un mismo dominio puedes listar las mismas a travez del active directory. Confírmame estas cosas y te doy un buen ejemplo a utilizar.

Comment: Gracias por responder, si tengo usuario privilegiado, me gustaria conocer tu ejemplo, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DIRECCIONES

Primero que nada debemos obtener de alguna manera las direcciones a las cuales conectarnos, esto puede obtenerse de varias maneras.

### Por el Active Directory del dominio:

Para esto seguro haya maneras más sencillas, pero yo utilicé esta una vez, funcionó, y la uso siempre, consiste en "extraer" el dominio de tu PC, conectarte a su active directory y extraer las "Computer"'s:

```
Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")               'Objeto local de la cual se extrae el dominio
strDefaultDomainName = objRoot.Get("DefaultNamingContext")      'Extraccion de dominio
Set objRoot = Nothing                           'Vacio el objeto local.
CortstrDefaultDomainName = Split(strDefaultDomainName, "DC=")
CortstrDefaultDomainName2 = Split(CortstrDefaultDomainName(1), ",")
set Dominio = GetObject( "WinNT://" & CortstrDefaultDomainName2(0))     'Objeto, reprecenta al active directory del dominio.
For Each child in Dominio                           'Recorro los objetos del Objeto-Dominio
    If child.Class = "Computer" then                    'Si el objeto resulta ser de la clase "Computer" (computadora)
        Computer = child.Name
        Do
            Err.Clear()
            On Error Resume Next 'Ignoro errores
            'CONEXION
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Do End If 'Para ir al siguiente ciclo del for, devido al error
            On Error GoTo 0     'Dejo de ignorar errores
            'OBTENCION DE DATOS
            'REGISTRO DE DATOS
        Loop While False
    End If
Next
```

### Por IP a "Fuerza Bruta":

Esto consiste en la tecnica nunca bien ponderada de For Each's anidados, seria a lo sumo algo asi:

```
For A = 1 To 255
    For B = 1 To 255
        For C = 1 To 255
            For D = 1 To 255
                Computer = CStr(A) & "." & CStr(B) & "." & CStr(C) & "." & CStr(D)
                Do
                    Err.Clear()
                    On Error Resume Next 'Ignoro errores
                    'CONEXION
                    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Do End If 'Para ir al siguiente ciclo del for, debido al error
                    On Error GoTo 0     'Dejo de ignorar errores
                    'OBTENCION DE DATOS
                    'REGISTRO DE DATOS
                Loop While False
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
```

O bien puedes estar seguro de que estas en una red privada y/o utilizas "Subredes" conocidas y por lo tanto seria algo mas corto:

```
Subredes=Array(0,1,210) 
For Each C In Subredes
    For D = 1 To 255
        Computer = "192.168." & CStr(C) & "." & CStr(D)
        Do
            Err.Clear()
            On Error Resume Next 'Ignoro errores
            'CONEXION
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Do End If 'Para ir al siguiente ciclo del for, devido al error
            On Error GoTo 0     'Dejo de ignorar errores
            'OBTENCION DE DATOS
            'REGISTRO DE DATOS
        Loop While False
    Next
Next
```

### Por "Enlaces externos":

Esto puede ser desde la ejecución de una herramienta hasta la simple lectura de un archivo de texto, la versión genérica seria así:

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "Cmd.exe /c Net View > C:\Windows\Temp\NetViewList.txt", 2, False, -2
Set objTextFile = FileSystem.OpenTextFile("C:\Windows\Temp\NetViewList.txt", 1)
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream      'Until es como While Not
    Linea = Trim(objTextFile.readline)
    If Asc(Linea) = -15441 Or Asc(Linea) = 239 Then Linea = Mid(Linea,4) End If  'Para eliminar el pocible caracter "BOM"
    Computer = Linea
    'Formatear "Computer" '(esto depende del "formato" del archivo)
    Do
        Err.Clear()
        On Error Resume Next
        'Conexion
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Do End If 'Para ir al siguiente ciclo del for, devido al error
        On Error GoTo 0
        'OBTENCION DE DATOS
        'REGISTRO DE DATOS
    Loop While False
Loop
```

### CONEXIÓN

En todos los casos tendremos un "ForEach base" el cual nos proporcionará una dirección de conexión (Computer).
Con ésta estableceremos la conexión al Instrumental de administración de Windows ([Windows Management Instrumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx) o WMI para abreviar).
Mediante esta conexión accedemos a los Servicios WMI.

Si tu usuario actual (de ejecución) tiene los permisos administrativos en las computadoras a conectarte (normalmente, si eres un administrador de dominio),
La forma de conectarte seria la siguiente:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & Computer & "\root\cimv2") 'Obviamente tenemos la variable "Computer" gracias al proceso mostrado anteriormente. (Puedes eliminar el "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!" si no realizas "configuraciones delicadas".. o en este caso es innecesario dado que no vas a configurar nada sino solo consultar.
```

De lo contrario, si pocees un usuario que puede conectarse en las susesivas computadoras, pero no es el cual ejecuta el script, el metodo para conectarte seria el siguiente:

```
UserAndDomain = ".\Administrator" 'Account WITH domain "\"
Pass = "" 'Account Password
Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objWMIService = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(Computer, "Root\CIMv2", UserAndDomain , Pass)
objWMIService.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3 'Esto es para añadir privilegios, al igual que el caso anterior, puede omitirse esta linea.
```

### OBTENCION DE DATOS

Ya obtenido el objeto de servicios WMI (objWMIService), destacaremos las [consultas WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392902(v=vs.85).aspx), por sobre las [clases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(v=vs.85).aspx) y las instancias de clases.
Las consultas WMI nos permitirán acceder (y si es necesario configurar) las distintas propiedades de las clases consultadas,
en este caso consultar las instancias de clases [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx) es obligatorio,
otros datos como el nombre del PC y el usuario logueado, como el espacio libre de disco duro hasta la resolución de la pantalla
pueden obtenerse mediante [Win32_ComputerSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx),[Win32_LogicalDisk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx),[Win32_DesktopMonitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122(v=vs.85).aspx) respectivamente.
Por la conformación de las colecciones de clases devueltas por las consultas WMI,
la única forma de recorrerlas es (indistintamente a si la colección es de un elemento o más) es el For Each. El siguiente código muestra una consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
Set colNetAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=TRUE") 'El Where aqui identifica la coneccion "activa"
For Each objNetAdapter in colNetAdapters
    Mac = objNetAdapter.MACAddress 'La direccion Mac
    IP = objNetAdapter.IPAddress(0) 'La direccion IP (es un array, tomo el primer objeto "0" del mismo)
    'IPX = objNetAdapter.IPXAddress 'Si tiene...
Next
```

### REGISTRO DE DATOS

Llegados a este punto tenemos los datos almacenados (de la forma que quieras, variables independientes, arrays, estructuras de datos, etc. es tu decisión).
Aquí bien utilizas el objeto de aplicación Exel, o lo vuelcas a un archivo de texto plano en formato CSV, o lo que quieras. Me iba a extender en este punto pero está claro que entiendes el concepto.

Comment: Gracias @Ricardo Galain de mucha utilidad tus ejemplos.

Comment: @Nelson un placer, espero consigas hacer lo que buscas.